# Tag navigation in vi

Tags: vim

With cscope integrated Vim, I can navigate back using the `ctrl-T` and see the current tag stack position using `:tags`. But how do I go forward in the stack? The only thing I could find from the man pages is to go to the function definition (like `ctrl-]`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use Ctrl+I and Ctrl+O to move forwards and backwards respectively through the jump list. This works with tag commands since they count as jump movements.

So to:

Jump to a tag: `Ctrl+].`
Jump back: `Ctrl+O.`
Jump to a tag again: `Ctrl+I.`

Answer (score 1):

There's no default key mapping, but the command to go forward in the tag stack is `:tag`. (You can easily `:nnoremap` a key to it.)

As Chetan Potdar has already answered, as long as you don't move around in the buffer between tag jumps, you can also use `<C-I>` instead.